# Android ViewPager Prev/Next Button

Tags: android, button, navigation, android-viewpager

Okay, so I'm developing an Android app that utilises a ViewPager to display pages.

Within each page, I have a set of buttons to use for navigating between pages (in addition to the swiping between pages). These buttons are for "first page", "previous page", "next page" and "last page".

What I can't figure out how to do is engineer a mechanism to enable a page change on a button click.

Anyone have any ideas?

ETA: To better explain the setup, the buttons are declared within each page's layout, and are inflated with the rest of the layout within the PagerAdapter. My problem is that I can't reference the ViewPager from within the PagerAdapter. Or at least, I can't think of a way to do it.

Comment: I have the same problem ( don't know how to reference the ViewPager from within the PagerAdapter) , and the Accepted answer doesn't answer that either ( just uses `mViewPager` without specifying what it is). So how did you get that to work ?

Comment: Well. That was four years ago and I don't have the code to hand. Don't even work for the company any more.

Comment: But I think I did something like having the mViewPager as a class variable rather than a local one. I based this part of the project on one of the 2.5 example projects, so you can probably find something similar to assist.

Since doing this, I upgraded the project to use the 4.0 version of things which was quite different as I recall.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Button:

```
Button yourButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        
     @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               mViewPager.setCurrentItem(getItem(+1), true); //getItem(-1) for previous
           }
        });
```

Function:

```
private int getItem(int i) {
       return mViewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
}
```

Comment: This will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`s since there is no check for the current position.

Comment: This will give some problems, Instead of 1 and -1 you must give viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1 and viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1 to next and previous fragment

Answer (score 46):

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
      yourViewPager.setCurrentItem(page, smoothScroll);
   }
});
```

Comment: I did look into it, and that was my initial thought. But the buttons are declared within the layouts which are inflated inside the adapter which can't reference the ViewPager object itself...

Comment: Then create a custom adapter and pass the viewPager as a variable? or better yet pass a custom event listener.

Comment: What is page and smoothScroll ?

Comment: page is yourViewPager.getCurrentItem+-1, smoothScroll is true.

Comment: @DennisJaamann Can you tell me in an answer how to do that or give a link? I'm a noob

Answer (score 4):

1) Make layout

```
      <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:weightSum="1">



                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/images_pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    >
                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_next"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/forward_white"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    />


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_previous"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/back_white"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>


            </RelativeLayout>
```

2) Set custom Adapter

```
        CustomViewPagerAdapter  custompageradpter;
        ViewPager   mViewPager;
        mViewPager = (ViewPager)shareImagesDialouge.findViewById(R.id.images_pager); 
         custompageradpter = new CustomViewPagerAdapter(this);
         mViewPager.setAdapter(custompageradpter);

    public class CustomViewPagerAdapter  extends PagerAdapter {


        Context mContext;
        LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

        int[] mResources = {
                R.drawable.emoji_1,
                R.drawable.emoji_2,
                R.drawable.emoji_3,
                R.drawable.emoji_4,
                R.drawable.emoji_5,
                R.drawable.emoji_6
        };

        public CustomViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
            mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mResources.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);

            container.addView(itemView);

            return itemView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
        }

    }
```

3) For next and previous button

```
         case R.id.img_previous:
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(getItemofviewpager(-1), true);
                    break;

                case R.id.img_next:
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(getItemofviewpager(+1), true);
                    break;
```

4) Make this function

```
  private int getItemofviewpager(int i) {
        return mViewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
    }
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written

Answer (score 4):

A failproof upgrade to [sweggersen's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13285950/3682535) and [Alex Orlov's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10853057/3682535) answer,

```
// For scrolling to next item
nextPageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(getNextPossibleItemIndex(1), true);
    }
});

// For scrolling to previous item
previousPageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(getNextPossibleItemIndex(-1), true);
    }
});
```

Add getNextPossibleItemIndex() method in your Activity/Fragment,

```
private int getNextPossibleItemIndex (int change) {

    int currentIndex = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
    int total = viewPager.getAdapter().getCount();

    if (currIndex + change < 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    return Math.abs((currentIndex + change) % total) ;
}
```

This way, you will be able to change currentItem without worrying about IndexOutOfBoundsException [as suggested by Heinrich's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852744/android-viewpager-prev-next-button#comment58527209_13285950). Note that using this method, items will be displayed like a circular list.

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1
```

But going back, it will stop at first item

```
1 <- 1 <- 2 <- 3
```

Answer (score 4):

Do it like this:

```
backButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.back_button);
nextButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.next_button);
backButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);//you can use GONE or even disable it. It depends on your layout 


    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()+1, true);
        }
    });


    backButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()-1, true);
        }
    });
}
```

To prevent IndexOutOfBoundsException you should hide and show the two buttons like this :

```
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if(position==0) {
                backButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }else  {
                backButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if(position < viewPager.getAdapter().getCount()-1 ) {
                nextButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else  {
                nextButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: viewPager.getAdapter().getCount() not resolve in viewpager2?

Answer (score 3):

I finished this project  with this code.

```
vPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    View tempView1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ani_dialog1, null);
    firstView = (ImageView) tempView1.findViewById(R.id.ani_dialog_next);
    views.add(tempView1);
    firstView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            vPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Why allways item 1? Good that your keeped "// TODO Auto-generated method stub" in the code

Comment: This will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`s since there is no check for the current position.

Answer (score 1):

**Update code**

```
Button preButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pre_button);
        Button nextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next_button);

        preButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem()-1, true); 


            }
        });

        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem()+1, true); 

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

First create an interface

```
public interface OnPageChangedListener {
void OnPageChanged(int position);      }
```

Next Implement your activity with OnPageChangedListener interface and do the below stuff

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Fragment1(this));
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Fragment2(this));
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Fragment3(this));
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Fragment4(this));
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Fragment5(this));
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Fragment6(this));
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
}
@Override
public void OnPageChanged(int position) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
}
```

In your fragments create a constructor using

```
private OnPageChangedListener listener;

public Fragment1(OnPageChangedListener listener1) {
    this.listener = listener1;
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
    super(manager);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    }
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
}}
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

kotlin version using view-binding:

```
binding.apply {
        btnNext.setOnClickListener { viewPager.currentItem++ }
        btnPrev.setOnClickListener { viewPager.currentItem-- }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
     int currentItem = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
     mViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentItem+1); //(currentItem-1)
}
```

only this code in button click:
 `@Override`

`getcurrentitem` is the actual item in `viewpager`, the next item is `currentItem + 1`