# Next and previous button implementation in android

Tags: android

I have multiple screens in my app in which each screen has next and previous buttons except the first screen. when I click the previous button on 3rd screen it needs to go back to the 2nd screen and when I click next button on 3rd screen it needs to go to the 4th screen. In addition to it, the data of the screens need to be saved i.e. when I clicked the previous button on 3rd screen then the 2nd screen with already filled should be displayed. Similar with the next button also. Can anyone help me to implement this?

Thank you.

Comment: post your code that what you are done so far. Then alone we can give you an idea from that

Comment: can you use fragment?

Comment: Your question is too abstract. You need to select how you are going to do your screens. There are 10th of ways.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android ViewPager Prev/Next Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852744/android-viewpager-prev-next-button)

Comment: Stackoverflow will not be there for you if you need a free code writing service... You should show at least a bit effort!

Comment: post some code so we can help you