# add next, prev buttons in slider image made by picasso and viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, picasso, android-button

I've made a image slider with help of viewpager and picasso, now i want to add next, prev button on the image, how can i do that?

I saw different answers of this but all of them are showing error

This is main activity where image slider is shown:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private int[] imageUrls = new int[]{
            R.drawable.after_cookie,
            R.drawable.before_cookie
    };
    private WebBackForwardList viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ViewPageAdapter adapter = new ViewPageAdapter(this, imageUrls);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

This is ViewPageAdapter:

```java
public class ViewPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private int[] imageUrls;

    ViewPageAdapter(Context context, int[] imageUrls) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imageUrls = imageUrls;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageUrls.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        Picasso.get()
                .load(imageUrls[position])
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(imageView);
        container.addView(imageView);

        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this method to your code

```
private int getItem(int i) {
   return viewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
}
```

then use this for next button

```
Button NextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

 @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           viewPager.setCurrentItem(getItem(+1), true); //getItem(+1) for next
       }
    });
```

and use this for the previous button

```
 Button PreviousButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
 PreviousButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

 @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           viewPager.setCurrentItem(getItem(-1), true); //getItem(-1) for previous
       }
    });
```

it will work fine ;)

Comment: where should i put the first code in Adapter or MainActivity and for 2nd and 3rd code, Should it be in Oncreate method or outside?

Comment: add first code in your MainActivity and 2nd and 3rd code in onCreate method

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852744/android-viewpager-prev-next-button).

Comment: @SurenderKumar it's answer is same a of Ali Amini and Im having problem in it please help me :(

Comment: can you please also helpt to add tost msg if user go prev for 1st img? please? @AliAmini

Comment: add it in on click event Like: PreviousButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

 @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           viewPager.setCurrentItem(getItem(-1), true);             Toast.makeText(mContext,"Previous",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
    });